# jQuery not picking up correct value from Partial View

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a Hidden field in a Partial View

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Type, new { id = "Type" })
```

In my JS for the page in document.ready function I am trying to get the value for this Field using:

```
var type = $('#Type').val();

alert(type);
```

The value Type is set in two partial views which then Render the other Partial View as below:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        { Model.Type = TypeEnum.Diesel; }
        <p>
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("_MyOtherView"); }
        </p>
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        { Model.Type = TypeEnum.Petrol; }
        <p>
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("_MyOtherView"); }
        </p>
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        { Model.Type = TypeEnum.Electric; }
        <p>
            @{ Html.RenderPartial("_MyOtherView"); }
        </p>
    }
```

However when I naviagte between the Tabs which load the content the alert only ever fires with the 'Diesel' value - I change the HiddenFors to TextBoxFor and on screen I can see the contents of the textbox gets updated to Diesel/Petrol/Electric on moving between Tabs but I cannot figure out why the alert is not getting changed?

Comment: Can you show rendered HTML code?

Comment: I think the partial view _MyOtherView is related to the Type you are setting, and for this, you should pass this Model to the partial view in order to read the Type, or put the content of _MyOtherView and explain the scenario you want please.

Comment: Is your js not loaded once (like only on page load)? Is your js in every PartialView? The alert will only fire once, if the js is loaded once. You will need an event to trigger the js code again

Comment: This code 'var type = $('#Type').val();' should be in Tab change event.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you used "Type" as an example ID, you seem to be rendering three partial views, each containing a hidden input with ID "Type". The result is a page with three inputs with the *same ID*, causing a conflict if you're trying to get their value the way you did in your script.

I suggest putting classes on them, for example "hiddenInput", and then updating your script to something similar to this:

```
$('.hiddenInput').each(function() {
    alert($(this).val();
});
```